# Systemd: Whats wrong with this unit?

Tags: systemd

I wrote this unit (`/etc/systemd/system/test@.service`):

```
[Unit]
Description=TEST (%I)

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/echo "%i %I" >> /home/vagrant/test.txt

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After I run `systemctl enable test@` and `systemctl start 'test@slug=test phone=999999999999'`, I don't see any file on `/home/vagrant`.

The output of `systemctl status 'test@slug=test phone=999999999999'` is:

```
● test@slug\x3dtest\x20phone\x3d99999999999.service - TEST (slug=test phone=99999999999)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

May 01 15:40:51 vagrant-ubuntu-wily-32 systemd[1]: Started TEST (slug=test phone=99999999999).
May 01 15:40:51 vagrant-ubuntu-wily-32 echo[2161]: slug\x3dtest\x20phone\x3d99999999999 slug=test phone=99999999999 >> /home/vagrant/test.txt
```

I tried to use `systemd-analyze verify test@.service` to check for syntax errors but the output is: `Failed to load test@.service: Invalid argument`.

Comment: With systemd 219, I found I had to copy my template unit to a new filename without the `@`, making it effectively not a template, e.g. `cp myunit@.service myunit.service`.

I then ran `systemd-analyze verify myunit.service` and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use shell style `>>` redirection in `ExecStart`. You need to get it to run a shell that can do the redirection for you, or set `StandardOutput=`.
For example, try

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo "%i %I" >> /home/vagrant/test.txt'
```